# Erro, php não insere dados no banco

Tags: banco-de-dados

Pessoal o php está retornando que está inserindo os dados mas no banco ele não insere:

```
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";


  $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO perguntas (nome, pergunta, resposta1,resposta2,resposta3,respostaCorreta)
  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");

  $stmt->bind_param("ssssss",$nomePergunta,$pergunta,$reposta1,$reposta2,$resposta3,$respostaCorreta);

  //Pegando dados via post 
  $nomePergunta  = $_POST["nome"];
  $pergunta  = $_POST["pergunta"];
   $resposta1  = $_POST["resposta1"];
    $resposta2  = $_POST["resposta2"];
     $resposta3  = $_POST["resposta3"];
      $respostaCorreta = $_POST["resposta"];

  $stmt->execute();


  echo "dados inseridos com sucesso";
```

Comment: Tenta mudar a ordem
$nomePergunta  = $_POST["nome"];
.................

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO perguntas (nome, pergunta, resposta1,resposta2,resposta3,respostaCorreta)
  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");

  $stmt->bind_param("ssssss",$nomePergunta,$pergunta,$reposta1,$reposta2,$resposta3,$respostaCorreta);

Comment: kkk, a ordem com certeza influencia no insert, mas se vc não por um if no `execute()`, mesmo que por outro motivo não insira retornará  "dados inseridos com sucesso";

Comment: Não está faltando fazer um query para enviar ao banco de dados?

Comment: Se você pegar a instrução e executar direto no banco, ocorre qual erro ?

Answer (score 0):

Se você tentar fazer assim:

```
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

//Pegando dados via post 
  $nomePergunta  = $_POST["nome"];
  $pergunta  = $_POST["pergunta"];
  $resposta1  = $_POST["resposta1"];
  $resposta2  = $_POST["resposta2"];
  $resposta3  = $_POST["resposta3"];
  $respostaCorreta = $_POST["resposta"];


$sql = ""INSERT INTO perguntas (nome, pergunta, resposta1,resposta2,resposta3,respostaCorreta)
  VALUES ("ssssss",'$nomePergunta','$pergunta','$reposta1','$reposta2','$resposta3','$respostaCorreta')"; //Coloquei aspas porque acredito que é string seus campos


if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
      echo "Pergunta adicionada com sucesso!";
} else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```